# Splitting a number into sum components

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, calculator

Is there a way that I can provide a number and excel would calculate the components that makes up that number from a limited subset (without exceeding the number provided)

e.g.
Subset: (1.25, 2.5,,5,10,20)

and given a number (25) the excel would write up 20+5 (or 20,5)

17 --> 10+5+1.25 (closest combination that does not exceed 17)

35 --> 20+10+5 =35

36 --> 20+10+5 = 35

37 --> 20+10+5+1.25 = 36.25

38--> 20+10+5+2.5 = 37.5

39 --> 20+10+5+2.5+1.25 = 38.75

and so on

Comment: Would you want to do this using cell formulae, VBA, or either?

Comment: @Robyn well if you could do it with a cell formula it'd certainly answer the question and be very impressive

Comment: It'd probably require VBA, and at this site they don't much like doing whole exercises for people. as it's VBA it's more of a programming problem but again the sister or bigger brother site, stackoverflow, doesn't like doing exercises for people.   So it'd be better to ask on another forum like https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/

Comment: Also it's worth thinking about Why you are asking that question. From where does the question spring from.  If you're trying to learn excel.. perhaps VBA, then I suppose this may need a loop - iteration.. And if you're trying to learn how to do that then there are easier ways.. so more of a progressive exercise that builds up your knowledge, would make sense. Like a VBA macro to display numbers 1-5.

Comment: There is a lot of ambiguity.  Can factors repeat?  Your subset are all factors of each other.  There are many ways to use them.  Is there another rule, like the fewest possible factors?  How must 60 be expressed?

Answer (score 2):

This was a fun one!

Somewhere in your workbook (I suggest a different tab), create a table of components **including zero** like so:
[image: Components Table]
Simply start with the word "Components", then add your numbers below, then choose "Insert Table" from the ribbon. Be sure to include the zero, and to change the table name as highlighted. This components table will need to be in ascending order but the creation of the table means you get that handy little sort/filter button. :-)

Then, somewhere else in your workbook, create the main table.
[image: Main Table with an input number column, 10 component columns, and a component sum column]
Add only the first column, and all of the column headers, then choose Insert Table again. I edited the Normal style's number format to be `General;General;` so that values of zero were displayed as if empty.

#### Columns:

Number - your number

C1 - `=VLOOKUP([@Number],Components,1)`

C2 thru C10 - `=VLOOKUP([@Number]-SUM(OFFSET([@C1],0,0,1,COLUMN()-COLUMN([@C1]))),Components,1)`

CSum - `=SUM([@[C1]:[C10]])`

Within a table, `[@ColumnName]` refers to the "ColumnName" cell within the current row. Therefore, in my version, a formula of `COLUMN([@C1])` evaluates to 3 since that's in column C.

So, for the highlighted cell in the above image, the formula of

`=VLOOKUP([@Number]-SUM(OFFSET([@C1],0,0,1,COLUMN()-COLUMN([@C1]))),Components,1)`

resolves to

`=VLOOKUP(**35**-SUM(OFFSET(C4,0,0,1,**6** - **3**)),Components,1)`

resolves to

`=VLOOKUP(35-SUM(**C4:E4**),Components,1)`

resolves to

`=VLOOKUP(35-**35**,Components,1)`

And so VLOOKUP looks for the largest number in Components that's equal to the first argument (0), and returns a result of 0. This is displayed as per the custom formatting of `Custom;Custom;` so that zero appears as blank.

(Well, shucks. The "**" is, of course, not literally part of what the formula resolves to, but is instead my failed attempt to put the changed parts in bold. If anyone knows how to get the effect I was shooting for, please fix it.)